# Deducing sequence convergence from inequalities involving sequence terms and a constant

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I have the following task:

> Let $C\in\mathbb{R}$. From which of the following inequalities can I deduce convergence for $(a_n)$, where $n\in\mathbb{N}$?
>
> - $a_n\leq a_{n+1}\leq C$
> - $a_n\leq a_{n+2}\leq C$
> - $C<a_n\leq a_{n+1}$
> - $C\leq a_{n+1}<a_n$

I first thought that I could use the Sandwich Lemma, but because I don't know if $(a_n)$ converges to $C$, I think that I can't use it here.

Then I thought that I could use the fact that if we have $b_n:=a_{n+m}$ with $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and if we know that $(b_n)$ converges, then $(a_n)$ converges as well. But this didn't seem useful either.

How can I approach this task?

Comment: I am not a native speaker so I didn't know how to express better. What I meant is that I don't know if $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)=C$ holds. Maybe this is better. And my thought was that if I want to use the Sandwich-Lemma the lower bound and the upper bound have to have the same limit value and because $\lim_{n\to\infty}(C)=C$ the limit value of $(a_n)$ has to be $C$ as well to use the Sandwich-Lemma.

Comment: Regarding the question itself, are you familiar with the monotone convergence theorem?

Comment: I think yes. Is is that every monotone growing and limited upwards sequence converges. And that every monotone falling and limited downwards sequence converges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of real numbers. We know that in the case of sequences of numbers, the monotone convergence theorem states that if $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a monotone sequence of real numbers, then the sequence converges if and only if it is bounded. So let's see every point:

1. we have $a_n \leq a_{n+1}$ which means the sequence is growing or it could be stable and $a_{n+1} \leq C$ which means we have an upper bound: in this case we can apply the theorem and find convergence;
2. we have $a_n \leq a_{n+2}$ which means the sequence is growing or it could be stable but on one subsequence and $a_{n+2} \leq C$ which means we have an upper bound but only for the subsequence: in this case we cannot apply the theorem and find convergence, since it could be the case that the subsequence with odd indexes is stable and the subsequence with even indexes is growing making $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ oscillating;
3. we have $a_n \leq a_{n+1}$ which means the sequence is growing or it could be stable and $a_{n} > C$ which means we have a lower bound: in this case we cannot apply the theorem and find convergence;
4. we have $a_n > a_{n+1}$ which means the sequence is decreasing and $a_{n+1} \geq C$ which means we have a lower bound: in this case we can apply the theorem and find convergence;